# Meteor client side settings

Tags: meteor

Is there a good way to store client side settings for meteor that would be load before any other javascript?

I would put things like api ids and other such into it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're not doing any kind of initialization, i.e just storing values such as your api keys you can:

1) Have a `settings.json` file containing your settings in your project dir e.g

```
{ 
   "public" : {
       "api_key":"value1"
   }
}
```

Then start meteor with this settings file

```
meteor --settings settings.json
```

Access this value on your client via:

```
Meteor.settings.public.api_key
=> "value1"
```

Comment: still naming the files for loading order and not for content only is a bad practice. There's a reason why they describe the loading order in a more detail, you have a lot of control about the order.

Comment: Nonetheless I've edited the answer with another way which could be used.

Comment: Also you need to rename the file so that it has an alphabetic precedence or even in the `/lib` directory it will not be loaded first. I wouldn't consider it bad practice because javascript file's names are not used in the deployed code

Comment: This is a useful way of adding settings. It would benefit all if the docs were updated to include the "public" notion if needed on the client.

Comment: @Akshat: The fact that the files is not present in the deployed code is not an argument. This applies to any compiled language as well. But then we don't name our file 0.js, 1.js although this would short and clear which files are loaded. Having issues with the file load order indicates a bad application architecture at all. But as you completely changed your answer this discussion is off topic (now). (Note that my meteor app itself has only one file: the package file. Everything else is packed in modules, which can define the order manually)